# Using python to scrape Google Maps, how to get more results?

Tags: python, google-maps, web-scraping

My aim is to get a comprehensive list of board game cafes with a view to getting data for this kind of thing: https://localtrust.org.uk/insights/essays/skittled-out-an-essay-by-dan-gregory/

My code is working fine at the moment, aside from only getting 20 results, despite `"num": "300"`
I'm on the free version of serpapi, so don't want to use all 100 searches testing ideas, if possible. Will see if I can get funding to upgrade.

Using JupyterLab in Anaconda. Here's my code:

```
# Sidenote: Redundant imports(?) Didn't work when I only imported serpapi as sp, but did with the line "from..." - would like to know why
import serpapi as sp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import csv

# Set up the query parameters
params = {
  "engine": "google_maps",
  "q": "board game cafe",
  "google_domain": "google.co.uk",
  "gl": "uk",
  "num": "300",
  "api_key": "7ced5dc1bb79652a66f31ce95172d460bf86be8371bb354165d1a3edfd804261"
}

# Send the request and get the JSON response
search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
end_results = results["local_results"]

# Extract the relevant information from the JSON response
cafes = ["name", "longitude", "latitude"]
for result in end_results:
    name = result["title"]
    latitude = result['gps_coordinates']['latitude']
    longitude = result['gps_coordinates']['longitude']
    cafes.append({'name': name, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude})

# convert the dataframe to a CSV file
with open('cafes.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])  # write header row
    for result in local_results:
        name = result["title"]
        lat = result['gps_coordinates']['latitude']
        lon = result['gps_coordinates']['longitude']
        writer.writerow([name, lat, lon])  # write data row
```

I tried searching Stack Overflow already, and I'm thinking of trying a town-by-town search, e.g. `"q": "board game cafe stockport"` using a list of towns and a max. radius of 5 miles (if radius is a possible parameter). Again, I don't want to use all 100 free searches on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to increase the number of results from a single API call in SerpApi's Google Maps API. You need to paginate through your results using the `start` ([documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-api#api-parameters-pagination-start)) parameter if you want to extract more than 20 results.

There is also no radius parameter that can be used to narrow your searches to a specific area. However, you should consider using GPS Coordinates as your `ll` parameter ([documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-api#api-parameters-geographic-location-ll)). Part of this parameter is the zoom, which accepts values between 3z (map completely zoomed out) and 21z (map completely zoomed in). With this, you can manipulate your results to get data from smaller areas.

If you feel like 100 search credits is not sufficient for your testing, you can always reach out to contact@serpapi.com to work out a solution that will allow you to test your implementation freely.

By the way, you shared your API Key in the post. I recommend regenerating it. Otherwise, someone else might use it. :)

Comment: Aargh! Thank you for pointing THAT out! New key generated.